# Where is github api reference?

Tags: github, api

I feel dumb, but I cannot find the GitHub API reference.
The https://docs.github.com/en/rest has a bunch of Guides, the "Getting started" mentions some "Rest API Reference Documentation" but that link only goes back to the Guides index. Where is the reference - list of all possible calls? Google remembers this url https://developer.github.com/v3, but it redirects to the Guides index now

UPDATE:
Sidebar menu is hidden at certain scale :D

Zooming in to 150% in Chrome on my screen is enough to hide it

Thanks to everyone for answers, just posting for the sake someone else does the same later :D

Comment: Do you have the navigation sidebar when you open the "docs" URL?

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes, it just gets hidden at certain zoom scale lol, I forgot about it

Comment: @darkdiatel Please write an answer to your own question and accept it. Otherwise the question remains open for ever.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because poster realized he had simply hidden what he was looking fur due to scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28 is correct.

Please a have look the left sidebar `REST API reference`
[image]

Comment: Either that, or scroll down the main page to the "All REST API docs" section, which is right below "Guides".

Comment: @u1686_grawity thanks, that's a useful alternative to their new mouse-centric design